# VB.NET ListView Problems

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have two list views, LVPRODUCTS & LVSUPPLIERS.

When I click a Productdata in LVPRODUCTS, LVSUPPLIERS will show the suppliers of the product and the Productdata will be inserted in a textbox which can be use to add another supplier for it.

QUESTION.

When I add a supplier to my product and save it . I want LVPRODUCTS to keep my chosen Productdata Clicked and LVSUPPLIERS will just refresh its data and show the new set of suppliers including the newley added supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I would record the variable using listbox.selecteditem and then after refreshing setting the selected item back to the recorded one.

try something like this: (*untested code*)

```
 dim item as string = LVPRODUCTS.selecteditem
'do your refresh
LVPRODUCTS.selecteditem = item
```

Below is a link to the property page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx#Y0

Comment: the code that is run on selectedIndex.changed should have the storing at the top, and just before the end the recalling, perhaps you could post some code or tell me what errors you are getting?